# Syntax Used in reduxbundler example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Could someone explain the syntax in this example below?  This is from the documentation from https://reduxbundler.com/ .  The part that is confusing is the doUpdateUser: function.

1. I assume userId and attrs are parameters.
2. I assume => with () is the start of the function.
3. Where does dispatch and apiFetch come from?  Are these also passed in?
4. In the function body are we calling dispatch and apiFetch called everytime?

I'm just confused about the structure.  Thanks.

```html
export default {
  // the name becomes the reducer name in the resulting state
  name: 'users',
  // the Redux reducer function
  reducer: (state = [], action) => {
    // ...
    return state
  },
  // anything that starts with `select` is treated as a selector
  selectActiveUsers: state => state.users.filter(user => user.isActive),
  // anything that starts with `do` is treated as an action creator
  doUpdateUser: (userId, attrs) => ({ dispatch, apiFetch }) =>
    dispatch({ type: 'USER_UPDATE_STARTED' })
    apiFetch('/users', { type: 'PUT' }, attrs)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'USER_UPDATE_FINISHED' })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: 'USER_UPDATE_FAILED' })
      }),
  // optional init method is ran after store is created and passed the
  // store object.
  init: store => {
    // action creators are bound and attached to store as methods
    store.doUpdateUser()

    // selectors are also "bound" and attached to store as methods
    store.selectActiveUsers()
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a function that takes two arguments and returns a function that takes one argument with (at least) two properties which are functions and calls both of them.

Comment: Thank you.  Great explanation.